# Bug in Google Sheets Formatting

Tags: google-sheets-api

I believe I may have found a bug in Google Sheets formatting or else my preferred option is I'm doing something wrong! * Brief rant - I find GridRange a PITBS!! Rant over.

I'm simply trying to format a cell and make the text bold. I send the following JSON request:

```
{"requests":[{"repeatCell":{"range":{"startRowIndex":1,"endRowIndex":"2","startColumnIndex":1,"endColumnIndex"
:2,"sheetId":0},"cell":{"effectiveFormat":{"textFormat":{"bold":"true"}}},"fields":"*"}},{"repeatCell"
:{"range":{"startRowIndex":7,"endRowIndex":"8","startColumnIndex":1,"endColumnIndex":7,"sheetId":0},"cell"
:{"effectiveFormat":{"textFormat":{"bold":"true"}}},"fields":"*"}}]}
```

And the *values in the cells* disappear?? I know the values are there because if I omit this styling code then nothing is altered and the values remain. What am I doing wrong? (For ref the fields here are B2:B2 and B8:G8). Any help gratefully appreciated.

I am sending this through the JS API but believe I have seen the same through the PHP too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `fields` parameter to `*`, which means, "I want to set every field.".  Since you don't supply a value but said you want to set each field, the values are being reset to their defaults (which is empty).

If you only want to apply formatting, you need to set the `fields` parameter to just the format fields, e.g `userEnteredFormat`.  See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#field_masks) on field masks for more info.

Note also that you're attempting to set `effectiveFormat`, but per the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData.FIELDS.effective_format) that field is read-only.

Comment: Fabulous - I simply didn't see it was read only. So how can one adjust the fonts then through the API? I see it - userEffectiveFormat!

Comment: Use `userEnteredFormat`, per the answer.